# How to show that $y$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and satisfy the ODE $${dy\over dx}=f(y),\; x\in \mathbb{R},\; y(0)=y(1)=0$$
>
> Where $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ is a Lipschitz continuous function. Then
>
> - $(a)$ $y(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in \{0,1\}$
> - $(b)$ $y$ is bounded
> - $(c)$ $y$ is strictly increasing
> - $(d)$ ${dy\over dx}$ is unbounded

Efforts:

If I take $y=0$ then option $2$ is correct and rest are discarded.

But I don't like solving questions by constructing examples and couterexamples. How can I prove option $b$ directly.

Thanks.